# Javascript says a member of my class isn't a function, yet I have defined it

Tags: javascript

```
export class Project {
    constructor() {
        this.player = new Player(new Vec2(16, 16));
        this.level  = new Level(100, 100);

        // create a canvas
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("id", "gameCanvas");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    UpdateCanvas() {
        let canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
    Start() {}
    Update() {}
    DoFrame() {
        this.Update();

        // render
        const canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        const ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
        ctx.fillRect(this.player.pos.x, this.player.pos.y, this.player.hitbox.x, this.player.hitbox.y);
    }
    Run() {
        this.Start();
        setInterval(this.DoFrame, 1000 / 60);
        setInterval(this.UpdateCanvas, 1000 / 5);
    }
}
```

i don't use javascript often but I wanted to make a web browser game so i started making a platforming thing
i tried to make this class which can be inherited to make a game

on the first line of DoFrame() `this.Update();` it errors:

```
engine.js:143 Uncaught TypeError: this.Update is not a function
    at DoFrame (engine.js:143:8)
```

maybe it's something to do with inheritance? this class inherits it:

```
class YJump extends Project {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    Start() {
        console.log("Game started");
    }
    Update() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` is not longer what you think it is, use something like `setInterval(this.DoFrame.bind(this), 1000 / 60);`

Comment: Can you show the part where you call "DoFrame"?

Comment: Titus: do I need to do the same with the other setInterval call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit complicated it has to do with the relation of `this` you should read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

and yes your problem can be solved easily using `.bind(this)` from parent or from `constructor`

```js
...
  Run() {
        this.Start();
        setInterval(this.DoFrame.bind(this), 1000 / 60);
        setInterval(this.UpdateCanvas.bind(this), 1000 / 5);
  }
}
```